# Can I put file content checks in switches?

Tags: python

I'm checking if there are various strings present in file contents at the same time and I am curious if this could be done in switches, which I'm moving the code to right now, because I have a lot of lines that look as the one below.

What *larsks* also mentioned in the comments, is, if I mean the `match` statement. Yes, I'm aiming for results like this statement, but I've also found another solution, which works for me in cases, where I am looking only for one substring.

My current code looks like this:

```
f = open('somesortoffilename')

if "string" in f.read() and "otherstring" in f.read(): variable = 'value'
```

And I would like something like this:

```
f = open('somesortoffilename')
def f(variable):
  return {
    'string' and 'otherstring' in f.read(): 'value'
  }
```

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "switches"? Do you mean the [`match` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=match#the-match-statement), or something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean the `match` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to make sure that we read the file stream only once. First call to `f.read()` will already have used all the bytes in the file.

Let's store the contents in a string instead.

```py
with open('somesortoffilename') as file:
    contents = file.read()
```

The `with` form makes sure that the file stream is closed after we fetch its contents.

The “switch” pattern can be implemented in Python with dictionaries (the `dict` type).

```py
switches = {
    'term1': ['string', 'other_string'],
    'term2': ['another_string']
}
```

We can use this lookup to check if any string corresponding a term is found in the file.

```py
def f(contents):
    for term, values in switches.items():
        if any(x in contents for x in values):
            return term
    return None
```